# How to write cloud formation to upload EC2 stored files to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I am not able to upload files stored on EC2 instance to an S3 bucket with the help of Cloud Formation.

Comment: Hi karansingh005. Can you please include what you've tried so far, including the relevant cloudformation you've tried? Please see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question and get the most out of SO!

Comment: I don't think [tag:amazon-cloudformation] is the right tool to do this.